# Architecture to support multiple UI/platforms

Tags: architecture, n-tier-architecture

I am working on a SaaS based model which would be used to support multiple UI, platforms(web/mobile/tablet/desktop). Currently the architecture is a 3-tier MVC model and I am looking for any guidance on reference architecture to support multiple UI and can handle the scenario better(might not be a MVC model).

Comment: MVC is a design pattern not an architectural style, SOA is an example of an architectural model.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading Chapter 6[Presentation Layer Guidelines] of this book Microsoft Application Architecture Guide. You can get it online.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is rather open ended and a lot will depend on your exact requirements (what type of UIs, performance criteria, security, etc) a common architecture would be to deploy a *RESTful service*. When implemented correctly it's a technology neutral and lightweight way to expose functionality. Your webapp could be as simple as a (mostly) static site that talks JSON over HTTP to your REST service.